# Javascript Promise to Observable Translation Needed

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

I've tried finding an example that could shed light, but I'm having issues translating from one to another. What would be a good way of translating this Promise into a **Javascript** Rxjs Observable? I realize this might be stupid to do in the real-world, but this exercise is more about me trying to understand Promises more (since I have a much better grasp of Observables than Promises).

edit: I don't want to wrap myself out the problem. I want solve this problem by exclusively using Rxjs observables. Zero Promises or toPromises involved.

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            try {
                const result = fn();
                resolve(result);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        }, time);
    });
}

promisifyTimeout(1000, () => {
    console.log('hello');
}).then(() => {
    console.log('done!');
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log('the thing failed! call support!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the RxJs from function?

```
const obs$ = from(promise);
```

Comment: I don't want to just wrap myself out of it...that defeats the point of the exercise. I want to compare the two and how they work, by exclusively using only one or another.

Answer (score 0):

use `timer`:

```
return timer(time).pipe(map(() => fn()))
```

should actually be all you need.